# Is there an Error on pg. 17 of Tromba's "Teichmuller Theory in Riemannian Geometry"?

Tags: teichmuller-theory, linear-algebra, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, banach-manifold

I'm pretty sure that this is a minor error, but I could use some help here. So the book I'm referring to in the title is [this](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783764327354) book (MR1164870).

On pg. 16-17, he is proving that the space of almost complex structures on a compact smooth surface without boundary is a smooth submanifold of the (1,1)-tensors.  He does by expressing the space of almost complex structures is the intersection of traceless tensors and the tensors of determinant 1. He then uses transversality to conclude the argument.

I don't understand Tromba's proof of the statement that the space of tensors of determinant 1 is a smooth submanifold of the (1,1)-tensors.  He says he uses the Implicit Function Theorem, but what he does doesn't really make sense to me.

I will use the notations that he uses in the book and present his argument, or at least my poor understanding of his argument.

Let $\mathcal{H}^s(T^1_1 M)$ denote the space of (1,1) tensors on a smooth surface $M$ of some genus $g$, which are weakly differentiable to order $s$ and are square integrable. (Let $s>3$.)

Let $\mathcal{A}^s = \{J\in \mathcal{H}^s| J^2=-id, \text{for any } x\in $M$, v\in T_x M, (v,Jv)\text{form an ordered basis} \}$. This is the space of almost complex structures.

Let $\mathcal{N}:=tr^{-1}(0)\subset\mathcal{H}^s(T^1_1 M)$. This is a linear subspace, thus is automatically a smooth submanifold.

Let $\mathcal{M}:=det^{-1}(1) \subset \mathcal{H}^s(T^1_1 M)$. It's easy to check that $\mathcal{A}^s = \mathcal{N} \cap \mathcal{M}$.

Claim: $\mathcal{M}$ is a $C^\infty$ submanifold of $\mathcal{H}^s(T^1_1 M)$ with $T_J\mathcal{M} =\{ H | tr JH = 0\}$

To use the Implicit Function Theorem, we want to show that $Ddet(J):T_J \mathcal{H}^s \to \mathbb{R}$ is surjective for every $J \in \mathcal{M}$.

It's easy to see that $Ddet(J)H = (det J) tr(J^{-1}H) = tr(J^{-1}H)$.

But now, Tromba goes onto say that $J^{-1} = -J$, and concludes that $Ddet(J)H = -tr(JH)$. From this expression, the surjectivity is obvious.  But this doesn't make any sense, since $J$ is just an element of $\mathcal{M}$, and there is nothing in the definition of $\mathcal{M}$ that forces $J^2=-id$!!!

My questions are,

0) Is $\mathcal{M}$ a $C^\infty$ submanifold of $\mathcal{H}^s$, regardless of what is written here?

1) Why does he get to choose a $J$ such that $J^2 = -id$?  Why is that sufficient to prove that $\mathcal{M}$ is a submanifold?

2) This argument does show that $\mathcal{A}^s$ is a $C^\infty$ submanifold of $\mathcal{N}$. Does that imply that $\mathcal{A}^s$ is a $C^\infty$ submanifold of $\mathcal{H}^s$? (i.e. is being a "$C^\infty$ submanifold" transitive?)

Thank you for your time. And I apologize if this is not an appropriate question here.

EDIT: I think some people misunderstood my question 2). What I was asking was whether transversality is necessary at all.

So we know that $\mathcal{A}^s=\det^{-1}(1)\subset\mathcal{N}$. Using IFT, we can conclude that $\mathcal{A}^s$ is a $C^\infty$ submanifold of $\mathcal{N}$, the same way one could conclude that $\mathcal{M}$ is a $C^\infty$ submanifold of $\mathcal{H}^s$.

Does it follow from this that $\mathcal{A}^s$ is a smooth submanifold of $\mathcal{H}^s$? (That is, without saying anything about transversal intersections?)

Comment: I realized that the answer to question 0) is "yes," or at least I see that the map $H \mapsto tr(J^{-1}H)$ is surjective.

Comment: Maybe I'm dense but isn't 1) just the Cayley-Hamilton theorem: $J^{2} - \text{tr}(J) \cdot J + \text{det}(J)\cdot\text{id} = 0$, so $J^{2} = - \text{id}$?

Comment: Why is $tr(J) =0$?

Comment: Sorry I confused $\mathcal{A}^{s}$ and $\mathcal{M}$. But then Cayley-Hamilton tells you that $J^{-1} = (\text{tr}(J)\text{id} - J)$, so $\text{tr}(J^{-1}H) = \text{tr}(J)\text{tr}(H)  - \text{tr}(JH)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A small typo: your definition of $\mathcal{M}$ is incorrect; shouldn't it be $\det^{-1}(1)$?

Anyway, I think you are mixing up two parts of the proof. The first is that $\mathcal{M}$ is a smooth submanifold. Indeed, using your computation, it is easy to see that taking $H= J$ you have $D\det(J)H = \mathop{tr}(J^{-1}J) = 2$ and so surjectivity follows.

The part about setting $J^{-1} = -J$ is only used to prove the transversality of $\mathcal{M}$ and $\mathcal{N}$ at the intersection: that if $J\in\mathcal{M}\cap\mathcal{N}$, then indeed $D\det(J)H = -\mathop{tr}(JH)$. In particular for such $J$ you have $Id\in T_J\mathcal{M}$ but not in $T_J\mathcal{N}$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

Yes, that should've been $\det^{-1}(1)$. I made the correction just now. 

But there is definitely a typo on pg. 17, since he says:

"[after using $J^2=-id$ to get $Ddet(J)H = -tr(JH)$]...It remains to show that $H\mapsto -\tr JH$ is surjective. Then the implicit function theorem shows that $\mc{M}$ is a submanifold with tangent sapce $\ker(D\det(J))=\\{H|\tr JH =0 \\}.$

Thanks for the clarification. I thought perhaps I was missing some kind of a known theorem or some feature of the Implicit Function Theorem that allows me to only look at those with $J^2=-id$.

Comment: What about my question 2)?

$\mathcal{A}^s$ is a $C^\infty$ submanifold of $\mathcal{N}$, and thus is a $C^\infty$ submanifold of $\mathcal{H}^s$?

Comment: @BrainDead: I don't have my copy of Tromba handy, so I cannot check the exact wording he used. If you are sure about your reading, then maybe you should send him an e-mail about the misprint. On question (2) I don't remember off hand whether any additional conditions are needed for the infinite dimensional transverse-intersection theorem. But the finite dimensional analogue of your statement is true: transverse intersection of two smooth submanifolds form a smooth submanifold of codimension the sum of the original codimensions. 

Comment: In particular: the finite dimensional analogue gives if $M,N$ two smooth submanifolds of $X$ such that along $x\in M\cap N$ you have $T_xM$ and $T_xN$ span $T_xX$, then $M\cap N$ is a smooth submanifold of $X$ with codimension $\mathop{codim}(M) + \mathop{codim}(N)$. 

Comment: @Willie Wong - Thank you for your answer. But what I was asking was whether the transverse-intersection theorem was necessary at all. I made an edit to my post to clarify what exactly I meant by 2). Please take a look.

Comment: I suspect the final argument will actually be the same. The proof of the transverse intersection in finite dimensions have a lot in common with the implicit/inverse function theorems (what you outlined certainly works in finite dimensions); and I think the same is true for the infinite dimensional case. An argument that gives you that certain "submanifolds" are transitive will most likely also give you the transverse intersection theorem. Anyway, I don't have any handy references for infinite dimensional manifolds. Perhaps you should check Lang's book on geometry?

Comment: In other words: I have a nagging doubt that transverse-intersection and a suitable notion of transitivity of submanifolds are probably equivalent notions given some sort of implicit function theorem. So I don't see what avoiding transversality will gain you. 